# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable with lambda

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I'm very new to scala and spark. Now I'm having an issue that makes me very confused. Please give me an advice.

I'm making `RDD[myEntityClass]` from `RDD[Array[String]]` using lambda. But I faced an error which says there is null value to parse String to Long. To investigate this I implemented a method which makes me able to use breakpoint.

However now I'm getting `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` and I can't find what's wrong. Below is my code snippet please help me if you can find anything.

```
def makingData() : RDD[MyEntityClass] = {
  .
  .
  data.map(row => toMyEntityClass(row))
}

def toMyEntityClass(row : Array[String]) : MyEntityClass = {
  var id = row(0).toLong
  var name = row(1)
  var code = row(2).toLong
  var parentId = row(3).toLong
  var status = row(4)

  MyEntityClass(id, name, code, parentId, status)
}
```

===== updated question =====

I'm updating my question to respond your advices. I've already had MyEntityClass as case class like below.

```
case class MyEntityClass(id: Long, name: String, code: Long, parentId: Long, status: String)
```

===== appended stack trace =====

```
Task not serializable
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2030)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:314)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:313)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:313)
at com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec.getDummyData(MyRepositorySpec.scala:40)
at com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec$$anonfun$3.apply(MyRepositorySpec.scala:66)
at com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec$$anonfun$3.apply(MyRepositorySpec.scala:65)
at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1681)
at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1031)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1691)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1678)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1690)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1690)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:287)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1690)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1691)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1748)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1748)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:394)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:382)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:382)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:371)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:408)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:382)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:382)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:377)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:459)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1748)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1691)
at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1320)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1691)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1794)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1794)
at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:519)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1794)
at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.run(FlatSpec.scala:1691)
at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:46)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1340)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1334)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1334)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1011)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1010)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1500)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper, value: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper@45e639ee)
- field (class: org.scalatest.FlatSpec, name: assertionsHelper, type: class org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper)
- object (class com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec, MyRepositorySpec)
- field (class: com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec$$anonfun$getDummyData$1, name: $outer, type: class com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec)
- object (class com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec$$anonfun$getDummyData$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
... 61 more
```

Comment: add `with Serializable` to MyEntityClass

Comment: Although your code is quite incomplete, it's possible that Spark tries to serialize your entire Class (i.,e. the class were you defined your main method)? This could happen if you make a make a closure on instance methods or variables etc...

Answer (score 1):

From the code given above, I understand that you want to convert 
`RDD[Array[String]]` to `RDD[MyEntityClass]`

We've 2 options here..

- Make a case class `MyEntityClass` which is by default `Serializable`.
  for example

  `case MyEntityClass(id : Long, name : String, code : String, parentId : Long, status : String)`
- Make a normal class `MyEntityClass` `with Serializable` then its eligible for serialization... ***Note : In general this approach is used when case class has more than 22 fields(productarity issue) and if you are using < scala 2.10***

> EDIT : After you confirmed that `MyEntityClass` is a case class, and
>   pasted Serialization Debugger stack trace, which reveals
>   `MyRepositorySpec` is just a test class which extends FlatSpec and has
>   makingData() and toMyEntityClass().You are using your test class
>   inside the closure which is the cause of this exception

***With below error it is clearly evident***

> caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper Serialization stack:
>   - object not serializable (class: org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper, value:
>   org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper@45e639ee)
>   - field (class: org.scalatest.FlatSpec, name: assertionsHelper, type: class org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper)
>   - object (class com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec, MyRepositorySpec)
>   - field (class: com.myproject.repository.MyRepositorySpec$$anonfun$getDummyData$1,
>   name:

#### Solution : Make `MyRepositorySpec` as  Serializable

Comment: do you mean still you are getting task not serializable ? if so I need complete stack trace and there is something called serialization debugger which will give exactly where this exception is coming. pls paste that in your question and ping me

Comment: Yes, it has been case class from the beginning. So I added full stack trace like you said.

Comment: what about this class `MyRepositorySpec` are you calling some where out side the closure? was it object or class ? if so where is the code snippet. you have to describe more. as the info is not sufficient. if not MyRepositorySpec is object make it as object and try. still I feel you have to give more details in the first place...

Comment: `MyRepositorySpec` is just a test class which extends `FlatSpec` and has `makingData()` and `toMyEntityClass()`.

Comment: I think that's the cause which is not serialized. its clearly evident from stack trace you gave. data provider class i.e MyRepositorySpec  make it as an object. it should work. if its not directly possible, move it to another object and then call that

Comment: Unfortunately, your advice couldn't solve the problem, and I found MyRepositorySpec is already Serializable since FlatSpec extends Serializable. Anyway thanks for your sincere advices, I voted up your answer.